# VNC Server for classic Mac OS?

Tags: remote-desktop, classic-mac-os

I'm looking to run a VNC server on some of my Macs running Mac OS so that I can access them from other machines. Google searching for generic terms was useless, for example "VNC Server Mac OS" only gets you results about Mac OS X.

More specifically, I'm looking for VNC server software(s) that would run on both 68K and PowerPC. What VNC server software is available for Mac OS versions 9.x and below?

Just to clarify: **this question is about Mac OS, not Mac OS X or macOS (Sierra/High Sierra)**.

Comment: Note to the user who edited the title: I have rolled back your revision as I am asking this about Mac OS in general, not just 9.x (not to mention, 9.x is not available for 68K).

Comment: I'm wondering if this wouldn't be a better fit on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com than it is here.

Answer (score 4):

There is already VNC-server software builtin to the macOS. Go to System Preferences > Sharing and tick the box for Screen Sharing on the left. Notice the Computer Settings… button on the right. Click that and you will get a drop-down dialogue with an option for "VNC viewers may control screen with password:" Enable that, and you should be able to use whatever VNC-client software you choose. I am not very experienced, but my research led me to choose TigerVNC, which I've used with success on Linux to control my Mac.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. VNC *IS* built into MacOS (Intel and PPC) and perfectly compatible with 3rd party VNC clients. As for classic Mac OS (9.x, etc) that might be best asked elsewhere as per Tetsujin's suggestion.

Comment: @SteveChambers I downvoted the answer because the answering person didn't read the question thoroughly. I would also downvote the sentence "Albany is the capital of New York (state)" trying to answer the question "What's the capital of Texas?".

Comment: Does the built-in MacOS VNC server have a reverse VNC feature like in TightVNC (https://verahill.blogspot.com/2012/02/debian-testing-wheezy-64-reverse-vnc.html)?

Answer (score 4):

The standard app in the old days to control Macs remotely was Timbuktu (Pro).

Selling of the app was stopped in 2015.

- A 68k version is available here: [Timbuktu Pro 4.0.6](http://macintoshgarden.org/apps/timbuktu-pro-4)
- A PPC version is available here: [Timbuktu Pro 5.2.4 & 6.0](http://macintoshgarden.org/apps/timbuktu-pro-524-60)
- A macOS version running in Sierra is available here: [Timbuktu Pro 8.8.5](ftp://ftp-xo.netopia.com/products/timbuktu/mac/885/TimbuktuPro885.dmg)

To get keys/serials you'd have to buy them at ebay or use non-legal sources.

Comment: I'm already aware of Timbuktu and I'm pretty sure I've even got an old copy sitting around somewhere. Reason for asking about VNC was that the computers I wish to control it from are not Macs, so wanted something with an open protocol. Backup plan if I cannot find a VNC server software is to put Timbuktu on a Mac (OS X 10.4) and then VNC to that to control these computers.

Answer (score 1):

## MiniVNC

> [MiniVNC](https://github.com/marciot/mac-minivnc) is a remote desktop server that has been written from the ground up for best performance on 68k Macintosh computers.
>
> [image: MiniVNC - MacOS screenshot]

It was originally an experiment to see whether a Macintosh Plus could be controlled remotely, but has since been expanded to support color on all vintage color Macs!

Despite the long time elapsed, I think it should be *exactly* what you were looking for.